# Passing parameters to ember components naming convention

Tags: ember.js

Which of the following is better practice?

```
{{my-component title=model.title body=model.body}}
```

or

```
{{my-component model=model}}
```

Is there any difference between the two, or does it not really matter?

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to not subjectively judge something like this. But let's see, what we can do from a few different standpoints.

First you could argue, that you can infer which properties are required for this component to function, the second not so much. That being said, we're not really even able to infer much more about the properties the component require, like what types they need to be etc.

The second standpoint would be, simplicity in the second component make it more attractive/clean. Especially when the properties you require for the component start getting out of control.

This could easily later look something like.

```
{{my-component 
   title=model.title 
   body=model.body 
   extraprop1=model.prop 
   extraprop2=parent.prop
}}
```

For now, I would say, use what makes sense on a component by component basis, and don't over think it.

You could consider integrating something like TypeScript into your project, and maybe start explicitly defining what type of property you need where in a component, without really having to worry about the api you expose to component via the template.

Here is a [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/5276db67c1fca24182c9d71ce309b27b?openFiles=templates.components.my-component.hbs) that demonstrates a simple test for those properties.

Comment: Is there any fear of exposing an entire model to a component?

Comment: I wouldn't be worried, if I have a nice test backing it up! That should let you know really quickly that some property is missing!

Comment: Happy to help, added simple test to post as a demonstration.

Comment: If you have nested components, I could imagine a scenario a few layers deep where being explicit would be beneficial visually/readably - but until you are in that scenario, it's probably a safe stance to keep it simple. `model=model` (I have to keep saying to myself from right to left - "let model be... model") shorter/simpler - but also, you can use this spot to make things more readable. `{{my-event-component event=model}}` ~ as for the tests - is sone faster? and if there are say, hundreds?