# How to hand off model data to component in Ember 2.x

Tags: ember.js

I have a route in ember which looks like

```
//fish.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      fishPrices: this.store.query('fish-price', {filter: {type: params.type}}),
      type: params.type
    });
  }
});
```

My `fish.hbs` uses `model.type` to change text on the page.  However, I need to hand `model.fishPrices` off to a component which plots the price of the fish as a function of time:

```
//fish-price-plot.js
import Ember from 'ember';
/* global Plotly */

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  didInsertElement() {
    console.log(this.get('model'));
    Plotly.plot( 'fish-price-plot', [{
      // ...
      //Need to access model.fishPrices here
  }
});
```

How do I access the model in this component?  I see a lot of information that suggests that I should be able to do something like

```
var fishPrices = this.get('model.fishPrices');
//do something with fishPrices
```

but this always ends up undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is directly passing it to the component props like this:

```
// route template in which you want to use your component & model
{{fishprice-plot model=model}}
```

Have a look at the following [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/68e81db1ce2c25697115f3185627bd73?openFiles=components.fishprice-plot.js%2Ctemplates.components.fishprice-plot.hbs) that demo's the first use case.

The other is injecting a service into the component with the required data.

```
// components/fishprice-plot.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  fishData: Ember.inject.service()
});
```

Have a look at [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/b9d4ce8baf176406fa84d35acdd515bb?openFiles=components.fishprice-plot.js%2Ctemplates.components.fishprice-plot.hbs) that demonstrates passing data to a component more comprehensively, and also [this part](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/components/passing-properties-to-a-component/) of the guides, as pointed out by @locks in comments.

You can also have a look at this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36876502/passing-parameters-to-ember-components-naming-convetion/36876855#36876855) regarding passing properties to your component.

Comment: There is to mention that you should name your data not `model`. So do `fishPrices=model.fishPrices` instead of `model=model`. Its much clearer, and then you access `this.get('fishPrices')` in your component.

Comment: The current version of the twiddle does an excellent job of demonstrating this ... it just don't work in my code for some reason.  I think the problem is probably on my side.

Comment: I'd like to point out that the [Guides cover this](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/components/passing-properties-to-a-component/) as well.

Comment: Thanks everyone I'm adding it to answer, I did answer regarding this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36876502/passing-parameters-to-ember-components-naming-convetion/36876855#36876855)